# How to add an image icon to a node in a treelist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-treelist

I've tried the approach used for the TreeView component using "imageUrl" but this is not working.

```js
var kendoTreeListData = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
  data: ContextSelector.data.tree
});
ContextSelector.tag.kendoTreeList({
  columns: [{
    field: "Text",
    title: "ConnectTo",
    attributes: {
      "class": "name-cell",
    },
  }, {
    field: "TimeBombWarning",
    title: " ",
    attributes: {
      "class": "name-cell",
    },
  }],
  dataSource: kendoTreeListData,
  editable: true,
  selectable: true
});
kendoTreeListData.read();
```

In each node in my dataSource, I have set "imageUrl" to "http://localhost:2431/test/Content/Images/PageIcons/FavOff.png" but this is not working.

Is there a way to display an image in a TreeList node ?

What I'm trying to achieve with a TreeList : [TreeView](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/images)

Comment: In your example, you set imageUrl in columns object ... but in [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/uPITi) from telerik's site, they set imageUrl directly in dataSource. Please, try it to place there.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I've tried to and it is not working